# Large memory consumption when setting background to dialog

Tags: android, performance, android-memory

I monitor my app memory consumption using android-monitor and noticed huge increase on memory cunsumption when showing dialog on the screen

I am trying to understand why this happens

In my dialog layout xml i am setting drawable as background to the root view-group:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="286dp"
android:layout_height="307dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/shareratepopup"
android:layout_margin="25dp"
>
```

Other then that i am setting two small drawables to ImageViews (about 4kb drawables)

The shareratepopup drawable weight 25,426 bytes (29 KB on disk) and its dimension is 964 × 1241

Is it make sense that its cause the memory consumption to rise ±13MB?
I know that i can reduce the dimension of the drawable, but still how is it that the dialog cause 13MB increase in memory? (which cause OOM exception)

Any clarification will help!